# Unreal virtual function causing unresolved external error

Tags: unreal-4, error-management

I'm making a base gun cpp class that just has the stuff all the other guns will have.  I have a virtual function called PullTrigger that doesn't do anything, I just want to have it on the base gun so i can implement it on the derived classes without recreating it.  in my header file under private, I have this code

```
virtual void PullTrigger();
```

I tried adding override after the parantheses, but it gave me an error.  As is, VS is uncomplaining, but Unreal says the function has an "Unresolved external symbol".  I have no clue what that is.  How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Unresolved External Symbol usually means that although you have declared the function in the header, you haven't created it in the CPP file.

Comment: I didn't know there had to be a definition, but it makes sense now that i think about it, because without one how would you derive a function from it?  thanks for the help, it's working fine now.